# Jest: Not able to test specific class with parameter in constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs

I use Jest as unit testing framework. I want to test a class called EDVApi (edv.ts):

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { FilePath } from '@ionic-native/file-path';
import {Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
import {Response} from '@angular/http/src/static_response';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';

export default class EDVApi {
webservice: any = "https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:YYYYY/";

public constructor(public http: Http) {
console.log('EDVApi created.');
}

login(loginData) {
let headers = new Headers();
let data = {
  loginData: loginData
};
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

let options = new RequestOptions({
  headers: headers,
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
});

return this.http.post(this.webservice + "login", data, options);
}
public sum(a,b){
return a+b;
}
}
```

In my test class I want to test the function sum of EDVApi:

```
import EDVApi from './edv';
import 'jest';
jest.mock('./edv');

describe('EDV Tests', () => {
it('Sum 1+2 should be 3', () => {
const mockEDV = EDVApi.mock.instances[0];
expect(mockEDV.sum(1,2)).toBe(3);
});
});
```

when I try to compile my code the cli gives me following error: Property 'mock' does not exist on type 'typeof EDVApi'. when i run `npm test` Jest tests fail with the message:

```
   the module which has no default export › Sum 1+2 should be 3

   TypeError: Cannot read property 'mock' of undefined

   5 | describe('the module which has no default export', () => {
   6 |   it('Sum 1+2 should be 3', () => {
>  7 |     const mockEDV = EDVApi.mock.instances[0];
   8 |     expect(mockEDV.sum(1,2)).toBe(3);
   9 |   });
  10 | });

  at Object.<anonymous> (src/edv.test.ts:7:28)
```

FAIL  src\edv.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol' of undefined

> 1 |
  2 | import { Http } from '@angular/http';
  3 | import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
  4 |

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/rxjs/symbol/rxSubscriber.js:3:26)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:10:22)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/rxjs/util/toSubscriber.js:2:20)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:3:22)
  at Object.<anonymous>.Object.setPrototypeOf.__proto__ (node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:7:82)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:10:2)
  at Object.<anonymous>.Object.setPrototypeOf.__proto__ (node_modules/@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js:7:82)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js:10:2)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/edv.ts:1:52054)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/edv.test.ts:3:31)
```

I tried many different solutions as described in the officially Jest Documentation, but could not solve this issue. Any suggestions?